# HHVM inside Docker and MySQL (outside) on host

Tags: mysql, docker, hhvm

I setup HHVM inside Docker on cPanel server with this configuration:

http://wiki.mikejung.biz/HHVM

Section - **"How to run HHVM in a Ubuntu docker container on cPanel"**

My Docker configuration is:

```
"Name": "/sad_wozniak",
"NetworkSettings": {
    "Bridge": "docker0",
    "Gateway": "172.17.42.1",
    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.13",
    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:0d",
    "PortMapping": null,
    "Ports": {
        "9000/tcp": [
            {
                "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                "HostPort": "9000"
```

and on VirtualHost of domain i add:

```
    <IfModule mod_proxy_fcgi.c>
            ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://172.17.0.13:9000/home/username/public_html/
    </IfModule>
```

I check that it works with curl:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 04 Apr 2015 22:34:52 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: HHVM/3.6.1
X-Mod-Pagespeed: 1.9.32.3-4448
Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache
Content-Length: 17
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

But i get MySQL error:

```
Error establishing a database connection
```

Outside Docker MySQL server has permissions to use any remote connection. I'd like to use "localhost" on server to MySQL server.

MySQL run on:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      498        19250361   3206/mysqld
```

How to connect HHVM with this MySQL which is outside the Docker?

Answer (score 0):

As documentation states, you need to add host address as alias to container

http://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#adding-entries-to-a-container-hosts-file

```
Note: Sometimes you need to connect to the Docker host, which means getting the IP address of the host. You can use the following shell commands to simplify this process:

 $ alias hostip="ip route show 0.0.0.0/0 | grep -Eo 'via \S+' | awk '{ print \$2 }'"
 $ docker run  --add-host=docker:$(hostip) --rm -it debian
```

After that you should be able to connect to host MySQL using address `docker:3306` from container.